# Invalid client response and OneLogin

Tags: onelogin

I has configuring an app to use OneLogin with OpenID for authentication, and although at first things were progressing and authentication was working as it should, I started getting some "invalid client" responses like the following:

```
    oops! something went wrong
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "client is invalid",
    "state": "aCLgxH"
}
```

this was observer in two different apps with the same clientId/credentials, so there must be somenthing wrong with the specific onelogin account. I tried creating anea OpenID app,with the same account, but I got the same result.

Any ideas/hints on this?

Comment: OpenID or OpenID connect?

OneLogin is in the process of deprecating OpenID, so I hope that's not what you're using.

Comment: I am getting the exact same error - using OIDC
I have even created a new OIDC app to make sure I did not mess something up

Comment: (I'm using OIDC)
Answering my own question: it seems that this error is related to the definition of "redirect-uri-template". If this is not defined, then there was the error I mentiioned in my question. Hope this helps.